# Angular2/Ionic2 - Implementing tabs with a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I am willing to implement a horizontal scrollbar (or some kind of) to support as much tabs as possible.

An image worth a thousand word (here is what I want to achieve)

[image]

Currently the tabs are implemented, working fine, you can check them out here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1no1sjZ9Lkv4glsUFnnU

```
import { Component, NgFor } from 'angular2/angular2';
  import { Tab } from './tab';

  @Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    template:`
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li *ng-for="#tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
          <a href="#">{{tab.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    `,
    directives: [NgFor]
  })
  export class Tabs {

    tabs: Tab[];

    constructor() {
      this.tabs = [];
    }
    selectTab(tab){

      _deactivateAllTabs(this.tabs);
      tab.active = true;

      function _deactivateAllTabs(tabs: Tab[]){
        tabs.forEach((tab)=>tab.active = false);
      }

    }
    // _deactivateAllTabs(){
    //   this.tabs.forEach((tab)=>tab.active = false);
    // }

    addTab(tab: Tab) {
      if (this.tabs.length === 0) {
        tab.active = true;
      }
      this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is to make it possible for the user to horizontally scroll (to the right or left) but I am not able to figure out how to do so.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: I need to implement similar functionality, but no solution so far.

Comment: See this solution: https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-2-scrollable-tabs

Comment: @user2570462 i want to scroll by screen also . From that plugin i can only swap that tab but not from screen .